# Evaluating $\int_0^{10\pi}(\lfloor \sec^{-1}x\rfloor + \lfloor \cot^{-1}x\rfloor)\,\mathrm{d}x$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, ceiling-and-floor-functions, trigonometric-integrals

My book has this problem:

$$\int_0^{10\pi} (\lfloor \sec^{-1}x\rfloor + \lfloor \cot^{-1}x\rfloor) \;dx = \;?$$

Now, the domain of $\sec^{-1}x$ is $({-\infty}, -1) \bigcup (1, \infty)$. 
How can you integrate $\sec^{-1}x$ in $(0,  10\pi)$ when $(0, 1)$ lies outside it's domain?

I checked Wolfram|Alpha. It takes $$\lfloor \sec^{-1}x\rfloor = 0 \;\;\forall\; x\in (0, 1) $$

Why? When $\sec^{-1}x$ is not defined for $(0, 1) $, why is it's Greatest Integer defined?

Wolfram Alpha gives $$10\pi - \sec(1) + \cot(1)$$ as the answer, while my book gives

$$\int_0^{10\pi} (\lfloor \sec^{-1}x\rfloor + \lfloor cot^{-1}x\rfloor) \;dx $$

$$ = \int_0^{\sec(1)} (\lfloor \sec^{-1}x\rfloor + \lfloor \cot^{-1}x\rfloor) \;dx + \int_{\sec(1)}^{10\pi} (\lfloor \sec^{-1}x\rfloor + \lfloor \cot^{-1}x\rfloor) \;dx$$

$$ = \int_0^{\sec(1)} (0 + 0) \;dx + \int_{\sec(1)}^{10\pi} (1+0) \;dx$$

$$ = 0 + [x]_{\sec(1)}^{10\pi}$$

$$ = 10\pi - \sec(1)$$

Comment: Add the ' \ ' before the trigonometric functions to render them properly in Latex.

Comment: I was trying inverted commas since then xD
Thanks!

Comment: Yoy can split it into cases, certain discontinuities can be integrated over by splitting integrals

Comment: Yes, but I'm having trouble with the part where they take $$\lfloor \sec^{-1}x \rfloor \; = 0 \;\forall\; x \in (0, 1) $$

Why is the greatest integer of this function defined, where the function itself is not defined?

Comment: Answer is: $10 \pi +\cot (1)-\sec (1)+1.0707359554357 i$.A imaginary part is computed numericaly. Book and Wolfram Alfa gives wrong answers.